# Help I an trying to find a series of books i read as a kid from the 60's/70's or even 80's

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for a science fiction series I read as a kid. It was about a boy who built his own robot and several other adventures. I really can't remember the name or anything and I tried asking my mom but she cant remember either. I only ask because my daughter would love to read them.

Comment: Can you remember what the covers looked like, or whether there were internal illustrations? Was it set contemporarily or in the future?

Answer (score 6):

Based on that very small amount of info, I'm thinking the [*Tom Swift*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Swift) series is a likely candidate.

Comment: Sounds like *Tom Swift, Jr.* to me.  One of these days, I've gotta complete my set.